# visual studio 2015 not loading stylesheets

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am a new user on visual studio, I created a new Project, the project structure has wwwroot folder where i store my css and scripts files. When i try to run the project my content gets loaded but the css and .Js files are not loaded. When i try to debug it show the correct path in the view source but, when i type the path in browser it says file not found/404 error.

```
<link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this is the way i am defining my css files in .cshtml files.
I have also tried with @URL.Content() approach, but of no use. tries dragging and dropping my files on the .cshtml file. But that too of no use.

The path that i access has a different map path i.e something like
mydomain.com/test/css/bootstrap.css

The path mydomain.com/test is mapped dynamically using routing. 
I was supposing this would be the issue, but i tried with the ~ character where it takes the path dynamically and show it on the url.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to Startup.Configure(...)

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```